# ERROR: tensorboard 2.0.2 has requirement setuptools>=41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.6.2 which is incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

gave this error in installation. Does this cause a problem?

ERROR: tensorboard 2.0.2 has requirement setuptools>=41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.6.2 which is incompatible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the exact same error:

```
ERROR: tensorboard 2.0.2 has requirement setuptools>=41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.6.2 which is incompatible.
```

Then I did the following three steps and it worked:

1) `pip uninstall tensorflow-tensorboard`
2) `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu`
3) `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`

Then somehow I found this result. It seems that it has been fixed.

```
Installing collected packages: tensorflow-gpu, setuptools
Found existing installation: setuptools 40.6.2
Uninstalling setuptools-40.6.2:
Successfully uninstalled setuptools-40.6.2
```

Successfully installed setuptools-42.0.2 tensorflow-gpu-2.0.0

Comment: I had to do a 4th step: 4) `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-tensorboard`

Answer (score 36):

I just did a `pip install setuptools --upgrade`

then

`pip install tensorflow`

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall TensorFlow using command `pip uninstall tensorflow`

Re-install it using the command `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

Answer (score 1):

Three steps and it worked as it said earlier

```
    > pip uninstall tensorflow-tensorboard 
    > pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
    > pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

But in case if you got error uninstalling "wrapt" try this two below command and hopefully everything works fine.

> ```
> conda update --all
> pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1
> ```

Refer to this original issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30191

Answer (score 0):

Modify the METADATA file of tensorboard. Let it not complain the version of setuptools.

This solution works on MacOS.
Edit file

> /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/tensorboard-2.0.2.dist-info/METADATA

Change "Requires-Dist: setuptools (>=41.0.0)" to "Requires-Dist: setuptools (>=40.0.0)"

Then it will not report the error.