# Errors while installing Tensorflow with Python 3.7.0 - why didn't pip3 resolve the dependency on its own?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, installation

I'm getting errors during installation of Tensorflow (cpu) into a virtual environment on Windows 7 box with Python 3.7.0.

My command:

```
pip3 install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

I got the following errors that did not prevent the process to complete.

> ERROR: google-auth 1.11.2 has requirement setuptools>=40.3.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.0.1 which is incompatible.
>
> ERROR: tensorboard 2.0.2 has requirement setuptools>=41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.0.1 which is incompatible.

**If I needed a higher version of any library, should not `pip` fetch it? Or does it mean that the repo being used did not have such?**

I look at `pip` as `npm` for Python. Is it accurate enough?

I did update `pip` itself before doing anything else.

The following question helped me to solve the immediate problem:   [ERROR: tensorboard 2.0.2 has requirement setuptools>=41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 40.6.2 which is incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104396/error-tensorboard-2-0-2-has-requirement-setuptools-41-0-0-but-youll-have-set)

I did the following:

```
pip3 install setuptools --upgrade
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip3 install tensorflow==2.0.0
```

However, I'm still interested what was happening *under the hood* here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here isn't that a newer version of a package was required, but rather that an *incompatible* version was required.

The version specification format used by pip is described in [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers). This format is [entirely compatible](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#semantic-versioning) with [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), which essentially consists of version numbers in the form of `Major.Minor.Path`. Using this versioning scheme, packages with differing `Major` versions are allowed to have backwards incompatible API changes, and so packages cannot be freely upgraded between major version without the risk breaking code.

A concrete example of this is the difference between Python 2.X.X and Python 3.X.X. With this change in the major version number, Python received many backwards incompatible changes, such as replacing the `print` statement with a builtin function. This resulted in many valid Python 2 programs becoming invalid in Python 3, and so developers could only migrate their programs to a newer major Python version after they had ensured that their programs would be compatible with the new API.

In your example, you have setuptools version `39.0.1` installed. You then attempted to install a package which depends on setuptools `40.3.0` or newer. As you'll note, the major version numbers of these two packages differ (`39 != 40`), and so pip can't be confident that upgrading the package won't break your existing Python environment.

If you instead had, say, setuptools `40.2.0` installed, pip would have gladly upgraded your setuptools installation to `40.3.0`. This is because changes to the `Minor` version are expected to be backwards compatible, and so any code that ran with setuptools `40.2.0` should work just as well with `40.3.0`.

Comment: Would using `--upgrade` change anything?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, passing `--upgrade` tells pip to upgrade the referenced package to the newest version, which includes updating the package's dependencies. Its worth noting that, by default, pip will only upgrade the dependencies as necessary, i.e. only the dependencies which do not satisfy the package's new requirements will be upgraded. See the documentation for the [`--upgrade` flag](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-u) for more information.